# clip-path svg works on image, but not on div

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

On MDN there is an example on how to use a clip-path svg on an image. The same clip-path does not seem to apply on a `div` element. Can someone clarify:

- Why this code does not work as intended
- A way to make an svg clip-path work on a div

**Example code ([based on MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#HTML)) clipping an image**

```css
#clipped {
  clip-path: url(#cross);
}
```

```html
<img id="clipped" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12668/MDN.svg"
    alt="MDN logo">
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cross">
      <rect y="110" x="137" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="137" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**The same clip-path on a div (which does not seem to work)**

```css
#clipped {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  clip-path: url(#cross);
}
```

```html
<div id="clipped"></div>
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cross">
      <rect y="110" x="137" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="137" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility) section lower down on that page lists "On HTML elements" as working in several non-MS browsers - but also has it marked as "Experimental. Expect behavior to change in the future." // https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path has further notes on what level of support exists in different browsers.

Comment: @04FS Firefox 70 is supposed to have full support according to the caniuse table. The example doesn't work there either. Fair point about the experimental phase. I'll drop MDN a note if the concensus is that it this is an (partly) unimplemented / undocumented feature.

Comment: Firefox does support clipping a div with an SVG clipPath

Comment: Please change the size of the div to `width: 300px;
  height: 300px;`

Comment: @enxaneta Good catch. It seems that the pixel size correlates to an unit within the svg :). If you post an answer I can accept it and close the question ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to your problem would be using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and build the clipping path with sizes between 0 and 1 like so:

```css
#clipped {
  margin:1em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  display:inline-block;
  clip-path: url(#cross);
}
#clipped.big{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clipped"></div>
<div id="clipped" class="big"></div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  
    <clipPath id="cross" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
       <rect y="0" x="0" width=".4" height=".4"/>
       <rect y="0.6" x="0" width=".4" height=".4"/>
       <rect y="0" x="0.6" width=".4" height=".4"/>
       <rect y="0.6" x="0.6" width=".4" height=".4"/>
    </clipPath>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: what about the opposite effect? any way to apply a *magic* attribute to hide the cross and show the other part by keeping the clip-path as simple as this one?

Comment: I guess we have to define 4 rect then: https://jsfiddle.net/umd5vLn2/?

Comment: well, you can keep both. I was simply wondering if there is a way to keep the same and be able to have the opposite (like with mask where we can invert white and transparent)

Comment: Both this answer and Temani Afif's answer seem to be correct. 

The `objectBoundingBox` solution is great if you are working with images with the same height-width ratio. Otherwise there is a risk the clipping path will get distorted. 

Temani Afif's answer pointed out that the size of an image matters when you are not using `objectBoundingBox`. The units in the svg correlate to the pixels in the div/image in that scenario.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @enxaneta it's all a matter of size. If you increase the size of div you will see the effect:

```css
#clipped {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  clip-path: url(#cross);
}
```

```html
<div id="clipped"></div>
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cross">
      <rect y="110" x="137" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="137" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Or you can use [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) to have something dynamic. The trick to have 4 white rectangle on each corner and white color mean *make it visible*

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:5px;
  background: linear-gradient(red,blue);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(white,white) top left,
    linear-gradient(white,white) top right,
    linear-gradient(white,white) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(white,white) bottom right;
  -webkit-mask-size:40% 40%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  -mask:
    linear-gradient(white,white) top left,
    linear-gradient(white,white) top right,
    linear-gradient(white,white) bottom left,
    linear-gradient(white,white) bottom right;
  mask-size:40% 40%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Clip-path` is not inherited. [Establishing a new clipping path: the ‘clipPath’ element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath)  W3C

Therefore, we will not get the child element cut by applying the `clip-path` to the parent block

It might be better to use the svg `<image>` tag instead of `<img>` and apply `clip-path` to it

Use div as adaptive container

```css
.wrapped {
width:25%;
height:25%;
}
#img1 {
clip-path:url(#cross);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapped">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cross">
      <rect y="110" x="137" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="110" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="137" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="90" height="90"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs> 

<image id="img1" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg"/>

</svg> 

</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what parent block and child element you are talking about. Are these the elements inside the svg? In that case I would doubt the svg is at fault since the same svg clipPath works on the image.

Comment: @RMo  <div id="clipped"> - parent block SVG - child element In your second example

Comment: I don't get thre inherited part here? we don't have any child-parent relation or am I missing something?

Comment: @Temani Afif In the link to w3C that I indicated, it is written unambiguously `clip-path: inherit NO` As I understood from the examples, OP wanted to apply `clip-path` to the div inside which the image will be located  Maybe I hurried to predict the wishes of OP :)

Comment: I guess inheritance is explaining another thing because clip-path will affect all the content of the element: https://jsfiddle.net/89r5t630/ ... maybe the child doesn't inherit the value but they are affect by the one of their parent (like opacity,display, etc)